# how to get exact current geolocation through curl

Tags: curl, geolocation

Is it possible to get the exact current geolocation with curl, like the browser does on e.g. https://www.where-am-i.net/ when it's asking for permission to get the exact geolocation?

Comment: Do you need HTML5 geolocation? If IP geolocation, you can use %> wget https://api.ip2location.io to ge the location

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/962270
$ curl ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8/country
US

Answer (score 1):

The website is using a JavaScript API to request the GeoLocation info from the browser.  Curl does not support this.   More info on the API here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

Answer (score 0):

just use this **curl ipinfo.io** and you will get summap of your current location.
and if you want only city you can **curl ipinfo.io/city**